# makefile: How to run a single command in WSL

Tags: windows, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm planning to run `make` on Windows which has a WSL installed.

Normally, I can run say `wsl date` in CMD or Powershell to temporally run the single command in WSL, but I can't manage to do the same in a Makefile.

I tried with the plain `wsl date`, it gives

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NLL, wsl date, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I tried with `$(wsl) date`, it runs the CMD version `date`, not the Linux version as expected.

Does anyone know the right way to make it work? Thanks!

---

A minimal case:

```
##### Call the WSL to run a command
call-wsl:
    C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe date
```

Run `make call-wsl`, it gives

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe date
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe date, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [makefile:3: call-wsl] Error 2
```

Comment: I don't know anything about wsl.  However using `$(wsl)` can't work, as that's just a make variable reference: if you haven't set the variable `wsl` to anything then it expands to the empty string like any make variable.  Is `wsl` a program, like `wsl.bat` or `wsl.exe` or `wsl.com`?  Or is it some other magical thing?

Comment: @MadScientist `C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe`

Comment: Is that directory on your Path?  If you use the fully-qualified pathname in your makefile does it work?  Please show a minimal makefile that has the problem, the make command you ran, and the output you got (not just the error).

Comment: Yes. `system32` is a typical location and is in the PATH by default. The example I added uses the full path and it didn't work.

Comment: You can try using forward-slashes.  If that doesn't work, I have no idea.  I wonder if the error is not that `wsl` is not found, but rather that `date` is not found.  But I don't know why that would be.  It appears to be something specific about wsl (in relation to make).  I don't know what, if any, special magic there might need to be to get wsl to work.

Comment: Both slashes are OK. I'm sure about that. `date` is not the cause as `echo` doesn't work either. Yeah, I hope there are some magic Words to Save Linux in make.

Comment: @MadScientist OK I just figured it out. It's because gnu-make in Windows is  a 32-bit program. So I have to use `C:\Windows\sysnative\wsl.exe` to correctly call `wsl.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Make installed by Chocolatey is a 32-bit program. So we must use `C:\Windows\sysnative\wsl.exe` to correctly call `wsl.exe`.